# Mysql indexes weird behavior

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a table with more than 200,000+ rows & 81 columns. I have total 31 indexes. Yesterday I added a new index on one column. Now when I use that column individually in a where clause, results are very fast. But as soon as I add another condition in where clause on different index column, the query becomes slower. For eg if I have columsn c1, c2, c3, c4 with indexes, all queries like:

`select c1,c2 from table1 where c1=a and c2=b and c3 = d`

are very fast. But when I added new index on existing column c5, queries like:

`select c5 from table1 where c5>a`

are fast but as soon as i add new condition like

`select c5 from table1 where c5>a and c1=b`

queries become slower. When i am saying slow, its slower 15-20 times. Fast queries taking 0.2 secs, slow queries taking 3-4 secs.

Help is much needed. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding a [composite index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) ?

Comment: You might want to look into covering indexes.

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to profile queries. Do not index everything. Indexes are not magic unicorns that you throw around hoping for things to get faster. Always specify your data set size, whether you use `InnoDB` and if yes, what's the value of your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable. Also, something with 81 columns and 31 indexes just screams "please delete me and normalize me for future use".

Comment: `select c1,c2 from table1 where c1=a and c2=b and c3 = d` -- Are you really selecting `c1` and `c2` when you know that they are `a` and `b`?  No hand waving, please.  Creating indexes is more subtle than you are imagining.  The best index for _this` query is a _composite_ index:  `INDEX(c1,c2,c3)`.  In _this_ case, the order of the columns does not matter.  Furthermore, given this composite index, `INDEX(c1)` is redundant, but `INDEX(c2)` is not.

Answer (score 0):

First you can use composite indexes (indexes on more than 1 field)

Second, you can check the query plan as

```
EXPLAIN SELECT [...]
```

(With the actual select statement of course.)

If you can show the output of

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
```

and the explains of the slow queries, we can figure out what to do.